# If functions are linearly independent for one $x\in I$, are they linearly independent for all $x\in I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

This theorem comes up when talking about ordinary differential equations. Basically, if we have a fundamental system, i.e. a basis $B=(f_1,f_2,...,f_n)$ of the vector space of solutions for a differential equation $$y'=A(x)y$$, we can check for linear independence ( if we are unsure if it really is a basis ) by checking that 
$$(f_1(x_0),f_2(x_0),...,f_n(x_0))$$
is linearly independent for **some** $x_0 \in I$. The theorem says that if they are linearly independent for **some** $x_0 \in I$, that's equivalent to them being linearly independent for **all** $x \in I$.

The proof is omitted, because this equivalence is supposed to be trivial, says the author of the textbook. **Could you explain why the implication from some to all holds true?**

I'd actually think there would be functions for which there is an $x\in I$ where all the functions happen to be zero, and then you can find coefficients which are non-zero so that you can say

$$ c_1 * f_1(x) + ... + c_n * f_n(x) = 0$$

$c\in \mathbb{R}$, but why does this imply that they must be linearly independent for all $x$?

Comment: What does it mean for a list of numbers to be linearly independent?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Guessing from the context, I think $A(x)$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $y(x)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and hence each $f_i(x)$ is a vector too).

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, that is correct, I forgot to add that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that your functions are linearly dependent at some $x_1\in I$, i.e. there exist constants $c_1, \ldots, c_n\in\mathbb{R}$, with at least one $c_j\neq 0$, such that 
$$
c_1 f_1(x_1) + \cdots + c_n f_n(x_1) = 0.
$$
The function $f(x) := c_1 f_1(x) + \cdots + c_n f_n(x)$ is a solution of the equation and $f(x_1) = 0$. By uniqueness, we must have $f(x) = 0$ for every $x\in I$ and, in particular,
$$
c_1 f_1(x_0) + \cdots + c_n f_n(x_0) = 0.
$$
But this last condition implies $c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$, a contradiction.